# Azure Policy to limit number of global administrator users

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We need to create azure policy to restrict user count with global administrator role to 5 at a time. But there is no reference of how can we get the role and count its member in azure policy. Please let me know no how can I approach this.
**Note** We need azure policy and not power-shell or portal steps to limit the restriction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to manage Azure AD roles using Azure Policies, Global Administrator is an Azure Ad role. Please refer this [document](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles) .

Azure Policy doesn't restrict actions (also called operations)and  azure policies are different, its for Azure Resources not for Azure AD.